# Phonegap: Slow response with vibrate notification

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I created a simple android application with jquery and phonegap.
When testing the app with phone, I noticed that vibration effect, that I have used to indicate that user touches a button, comes after a delay of maybe 0,5 seconds. This is way too long delay and just confuses the user.

Is this just the downside of using phonegap? Or is there any configuration or additional frameworks which could be used to make the app response and produce the vibration more quickly?

I installed the vibration plugin like this:
phonegap local plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-vibration.git

I use the code below to create the vibration effect.

```
navigator.notification.vibrate(200);
```

My phone gap version is 
3.0.0-0.14.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the delay is being caused by the vibrate function and not the act of clicking the button itself? Depending what event you use to determine if your button is clicked, Webkit Mobile browsers can add a 300ms delay, resulting in the sort of lag you're experiencing.

It might be worth checking out [this article](http://phonegap-tips.com/articles/fast-touch-event-handling-eliminate-click-delay.html) on eliminating click delay in Phonegap. Personally, I used the [fastclick library](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick) to resolve the issue in my apps.

Comment: Thanks! You are probably right, it seems that there is the 300ms delay. I'll try fastclick and come back to mark your answer as correct if fastclick works.

Comment: Using for example fastclick significantly reduces the delay. I also noticed that in native app the response when touching comes right away (it doesn't wait that you lift your finger) whereas in phonegap app the response comes after you release your finger. Is there anyway around this?

Comment: Try using the "touchstart" event which is triggered when you first touch the screen

Comment: Touchstart works. However, When I included jquery mobile 1.3.2, I started experiencing occasional delays again.